# Проблема с gridheight

Tags: java, swing

Объясните, что я делаю не так. Нужно сделать так, чтоб кнопка "=" была в два ряда. Использую GridBagLayout, для этой кнопки прописан gridheight = 2, но ей пофиг.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Calculator {
    JFrame frame;
    long firstValue;
    long secondValue;
    long result;
    String operation;
    GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();

public static void main (String[] args) {
    Calculator calc = new Calculator();
    calc.start();
}

public void start() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(250, 400);
    gbl.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0};
    gbl.rowWeights = new double[]{1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0};

    JTextField display = new JTextField(16);
    JTextField displayMemory = new JTextField(16);
    JPanel panelButtons = new JPanel();
    JPanel panelDisplays = new JPanel();
    JButton button0 = new JButton("0");
    JButton button1 = new JButton("1");
    JButton button2 = new JButton("2");
    JButton button3 = new JButton("3");
    JButton button4 = new JButton("4");
    JButton button5 = new JButton("5");
    JButton button6 = new JButton("6");
    JButton button7 = new JButton("7");
    JButton button8 = new JButton("8");
    JButton button9 = new JButton("9");
    JButton buttonChange = new JButton("+/-");
    JButton buttonRes = new JButton("C");
    JButton buttonComma = new JButton(".");
    JButton buttonBack = new JButton("<-");
    JButton buttonSum = new JButton("+");
    JButton buttonDif = new JButton("-");
    JButton buttonProd = new JButton("*");
    JButton buttonDiv = new JButton("/");
    JButton buttonTotal = new JButton("=");

    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, panelDisplays);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panelButtons);

    panelDisplays.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panelButtons.setLayout(gbl);
    display.setEditable(false);
    displayMemory.setEditable(false);
    //
    panelDisplays.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, displayMemory);
    panelDisplays.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, display);
    display.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
    displayMemory.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
    //

    panelButtons.add(buttonSum, constraints(0, 0));
    panelButtons.add(buttonDif, constraints(1, 0));
    panelButtons.add(buttonProd, constraints(2, 0));
    panelButtons.add(buttonDiv, constraints(3, 0));
    //
    panelButtons.add(button7, constraints(0, 1));
    panelButtons.add(button8, constraints(1, 1));
    panelButtons.add(button9, constraints(2, 1));
    panelButtons.add(buttonRes, constraints(3, 1));
    //
    panelButtons.add(button4, constraints(0, 2));
    panelButtons.add(button5, constraints(1, 2));
    panelButtons.add(button6, constraints(2, 2));
    panelButtons.add(new JButton(), constraints(3, 2));
    //
    panelButtons.add(button1, constraints(0, 3));
    panelButtons.add(button2, constraints(1, 3));
    panelButtons.add(button3, constraints(2, 3));

    //
    panelButtons.add(button0, constraints(0, 4));
    panelButtons.add(buttonComma, constraints(1, 4));
    panelButtons.add(buttonChange, constraints(2, 4));

    GridBagConstraints constraints;
    constraints = constraints(3, 4);
    constraints.gridheight = 2;
    panelButtons.add(buttonTotal, constraints);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    button0.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            display.setText(display.getText() + "0");
        }
    });

    button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            display.setText(display.getText() + "1");
        }
    });

    button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            display.setText(display.getText() + "2");
        }
    });

    button3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            display.setText(display.getText() + "3");
        }
    });

    button4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            display.setText(display.getText() + "4");
        }
    });

    button5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            display.setText(display.getText() + "5");
        }
    });

    button6.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            display.setText(display.getText() + "6");
        }
    });

    button7.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            display.setText(display.getText() + "7");
        }
    });

    button8.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            display.setText(display.getText() + "8");
        }
    });

    button9.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            display.setText(display.getText() + "9");
        }
    });

    buttonRes.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            display.setText("");
        }
    });

    buttonSum.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            firstValue = Integer.valueOf(display.getText());
            display.setText("");
            operation = "+";
        }
    });

    buttonDif.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            firstValue = Integer.valueOf(display.getText());
            display.setText("");
            operation = "-";
        }
    });

    buttonDiv.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            firstValue = Integer.valueOf(display.getText());
            display.setText("");
            operation = "/";
        }
    });

    buttonProd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            firstValue = Integer.valueOf(display.getText());
            display.setText("");
            operation = "*";
        }
    });

    buttonTotal.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            long secondValue = Integer.valueOf(display.getText());
            switch (operation) {
                case "+":
                    display.setText((firstValue + secondValue) + "");
                    break;
                case "-":
                    display.setText((firstValue - secondValue) + "");
                    break;
                case "/":
                    display.setText((firstValue / secondValue) + "");
                    break;
                case "*":
                    display.setText((firstValue * secondValue) + "");
                    break;
                default:
                    display.setText("");
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

    buttonChange.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            long value = Integer.valueOf(display.getText());
            display.setText(-(value) + "");
        }
    });

    buttonBack.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String value = display.getText();
            display.setText(value.substring(0, value.length() - 1));
        }
    });
}

private static GridBagConstraints constraints(int x, int y) {
    final GridBagConstraints result = new GridBagConstraints();
    result.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    result.gridx = x;
    result.gridy = y;
    return result;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> constraints = constraints(3, 4); поменяйте на constraints = constraints(3, 3);. Кнопка должна быть в одном ряду с "1", "2", "3", и занимать два ряда по вертикали.